# Not clickable element when I narrow the page

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, dom, css-position

I have a problem with my exit page element. I create a big "X" on the right side of my page. This is clickable element for exit from current content.

There is a code of this element:

```
.section-modal .close-modal {
    position: fixed;
    top: 25px;
    right: 25px;
    width: 75px;
    height: 75px;
    background-color: transparent;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.section-modal .close-modal:hover {
    opacity: .3;
}

.section-modal .close-modal .lr {
    z-index: 1051;
    width: 5px;
    height: 75px;
    margin-left: 35px;
    background-color: #222;
    -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(45deg);
    transform: rotate(45deg);
}

.section-modal .close-modal .lr .rl {
    z-index: 1052;
    width: 5px;
    height: 75px;
    background-color: #222;
    -webkit-transform: rotate(90deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(90deg);
    transform: rotate(90deg);
}
```

I have a logo image on the top middle of the page. Here is a code:

```
     <div class="close-modal" data-dismiss="modal">
       <div class="lr">
         <div class="rl">

         </div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
           <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12">
              <img src="img\Logo2.png" class="img-responsive" style="margin: 0 auto; z-index: -1" alt="...">
```

When I narrow the page I have "X" near my logo but I can not click and return to main page. I can not solve this solution. Please help.

If You need some more info please tell me I'll edit a question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it's hard to tell from your code, but I'm guessing the problem is that the logo is overlapping the 'x' button. To make sure , right click the 'x' and choose 'Inspect element'.

If the element tab is opened focused on the img tag and not on the 'x' then that is your problem., to solve it, give it a z-index:

```
.section-modal .close-modal {
    position: fixed;
    top: 25px;
    right: 25px;
    width: 75px;
    height: 75px;
    background-color: transparent;
    cursor: pointer;
    z-index: 100
}
```

Comment: That is correct i missed one z-index in my code. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

This might be a stacking context issue.

More infos for a complete understanding of z-index behaviors :

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Positioning/Understanding_z_index/The_stacking_context
- https://philipwalton.com/articles/what-no-one-told-you-about-z-index/